# AsyncTask with Dialog to internet unavailable then end entire app

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity, android-dialog

I'm developing an app that makes requests to a web service more often. What I want to do is, when internet is not available or disconnected then instead of proceeding to request; app should show a message indicating unavailability of internet and kill itself. I've this code working fine with me -

```
public GetXMLFromServer(Context context, GetXMLCallback gc,
          ArrayList<NameValuePair> params, String message) {
    this.context = context;
    this.gc = gc;
    this.postParameters = params;
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.context);
    this.message = message;
}

protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
    progressDialog.setMessage(message);
    progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    gc.onSuccess(result);   
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String response = null;     
    try{
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {         
        } else if (netInfo == null) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.context).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Connection Problem");
            alertDialog.setMessage("You are not connected to Internet");
            alertDialog.setButton("Exit",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                                
                            isAvailable=false;
                            return;
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
        }

        /*if(isAvailable==false){
            then finish the calling activity or entire app.
        }*/
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    try {
        response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(this.urlToFetch,
                this.postParameters);           
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
  }`
```

Now my problem is, I can't figure out how to end entire app or calling activity before  making a request and crashing the app because of there is unavailability of internet. (Commented part of code is where I want to stop app and end it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question I have is, why don't you check the network connectivity before you start the `AsyncTask()`?

Given that, here's what you need to do if you still want to include it in the `AsyncTask()`. What you want to do is cancel the AsyncTask. There's two keys to doing this.

1. Call the `cancel()` function.
2. Check in appropriate locations (`doInBackground(...)` within the AsyncTask `isCancelled()`. If you are canceled, then end the function as soon as possible.

As far as letting the user know, I suggest you pop up a Dialog, and in the `onClick()` method in the dialog, `finish()` the activity.

It might be easier to do this if you put your dialog in an `onCreateDialog()`, as is shown in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). Then the parent activity will be the application, not an AsyncTask, and thus the `finish()` statement will be correct.

Comment: (Sorry for my poor knowledge)`cancel()` is to be called from calling activity's `onDestroy()` method (i guess). But if internet is not available I can't finish the calling activity from `onClick()` of dialog since I'm not having right context of calling activity. (and it's saying, `finish()` is undefined as well) `isCanceled` will be true only if `cancel` is called. So how to do this? :(

Comment: Added more detail. The cancel() must be called explicitly, but looking closer are your code, it seems unnessicary. A better method, however, might be to check the connectivity of the network before you start the `AsyncTask()`

Comment: i think the reason i can't call `finish()` is it is belong to activity that `extends` `Activity` and not class that `extends` `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I tried that before asking here. Unfortunately, when i did it i can show the message saying internet is unavailable but after clicking on OK, it continues to make connection and then application crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the comment with

```
return "someSpecificString";
```

and in onPostExecute()

```
if (result.equals("someSpecificString")
  MyActivity.this.finish();
```

Comment: tried it. It is now saying `finish()` is undefined or cast it to "something".

Comment: TheNameOfTheActivityWhereTheCodeYouShowedIs.this.finish() doesn't work?

Comment: sadly, yes. it doesn't work. I thought it will work. :(
and one more thing, the above mentioned class is separate and is to be called from various activities. And those calling activities has to be finished.

Comment: i think the reason i can't call `finish()` is it is belong to activity that `extends` `Activity` and not class that `extends` `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Does your class (the one you listed code from) have a context from anywhere? if so ((Activity) context).finish(); If not, can you provide it with a context in its constructor? Or even better I just found this on SO android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Comment: Yes, I have the context of calling activity but it keeps on saying finish() is undefined and cast it to an object. I tried your suggestion putting `Activity` as cast but that didn't worked. Trying your other suggestion. thanks man.